# How to accept a list of languages as an HTTP request from a HTML form?

Tags: azure-functions-core-tools

I have created a simple custom web page that allows a user to select multiple languages of their choice.

My question: How can this be implemented by accepting a list of languages as a HTTP request from a custom web page, and then loop over them in Azure logic app? What I means is that, since [Azure Logic apps are HTTP triggered][1], can the custom web page simply make a request to that endpoint directly? For example, when we call the logic app from custom web page, how can we ensure that when a user submits the form, I make a POST to the logic app URL and pass in the body a content which is something like this:

Comment: You can't make an API accept what it doesn't accept.

Comment: @HereticMonkey yes that's why I was asking if that's something that can be done without the use of the API.

Comment: But you're still calling the API, right? With a list of languages? That appears to be what that `fetch` is doing...

Comment: @HereticMonkey  I think my JavaScript is incorrect. I was just showing my thinking, but that probably won't work. Let me remove the JS from my question so it does't confuse.

Comment: Ok, so you have an endpoint then returns some data, and in the request, you can send it a single language for that data, correct? But you want a copy of the data for every selected language, correct?

Comment: @GarrettMotzner Hi Garrett, yes that's correct.

Comment: Alright, so that means you would send one http request (probably with `fetch`) for each checkbox clicked, and then add them to the page (or do whatever processing you do) as they come back, right?

Comment: @GarrettMotzner yes... So for example if the user checks both English and Dutch. I   want to send them as HTTP request.

Comment: @GarrettMotzner can you assist on this or is it out of your scope?

Comment: I got stuck finding a CORS enabled sample api to send data to, (postman echo doesn't work), but this should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After discussing the problem, what it looks like you need is to send data to an [Azure Logic HTTP endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-reqres). That's fairly straightforward, and as you can send data in whatever json shape you need to that endpoint, doesn't need anything special (like looping over multiple requests).

Here's an example that submits one web request for each language. It uses `FormData` to access the `<form />` element and then gets all the `language` values, making a `fetch` request with the list of languages. It then logs the result. You probably want to do something other than logging the result, but hopefully this will get you started.

```js
function fetchForLanguages(languages) {
  console.info('starting fetch for', languages)
  return fetch("https://reqres.in/api/users", { // this should be your azure provided endpoint instead
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      languages: languages
    })
  }).then(response => {
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error(`Network response was not ok: ${response.status} ${response.statusText}`);
    }
    return response.json()
  })
}


function handleSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  const data = new FormData(event.currentTarget)
  const languages = data.getAll('language')
  console.info('languages selected:', languages)
  fetchForLanguages(languages)
    .then((result) => console.log('got result:', result))
}

let form = document.getElementById('language-form')
form.addEventListener('submit', handleSubmit)
```

```html
<form id="language-form">
  <ul>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="language" value="english"> English</label></li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="language" value="spanish"> Spanish</label></li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="language" value="vietnamese"> Vietnamese</label></li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="language" value="somali"> Somali</label></li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="language" value="chinese"> Chinese</label></li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="language" value="amharic"> Amharic</label></li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="language" value="korean"> Korean</label></li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="language" value="russian"> Russian</label></li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="language" value="tagalog"> Tagalog</label></li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="language" value="arabic"> Arabic</label></li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="language" value="khmer"> Khmer</label></li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="language" value="thai"> Thai</label></li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="language" value="lao"> Lao</label></li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="language" value="japanese"> Japanese</label></li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="language" value="deutsch"> Deutsch</label></li>
  </ul>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```